# si-cher-lich vs. sich-er-lich

Tags: hyphenation

Das Wort *sicherlich* wird laut Duden *si-cher-lich* getrennt. Meiner Intuition folgend hätte ich eher *sich-er-lich* geschrieben. Viele meiner Kollegen im Büro hätten den gleichen Fehler gemacht.

Gibt es eventuell eine zugrunde liegende Regel, die mir auch bei anderen Wörtern helfen kann, oder ist auswendig lernen angesagt?

Comment: Das "Problem" bei *sicherlich* ist, dass der Konsonant 'ch' [ç] im Silbengelenk steht, d.h. eigentlich zu beiden (Sprech-)Silben gehört. Bei anderen Konsonanten würde hier eine Verdoppelung stattfinden: *sitterlich* (Nonsens-Wort, bei dem [ç] durch [t] ersetzt wurde). In der Trennung nach (Schreib-)Silben würde dann der Doppelkonsonant auf die Silben aufgeteilt werden: *sit-ter-lich*. Da aber *ch* für einen Konsonanten steht, können wir nicht (bzw. tun es nicht) *sich-cher-lich* schreiben. Deine Intuition, dass 'ch' auch zur ersten Silbe gehört, ist also nicht wirklich falsch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jeder **Vokal** ist Kern einer eigenen Sprechsilbe (Diphthonge und Umlaute zählen als einzelne Vokale).

Eine weitere Grundregel ist, dass der **letzte Konsonant zur nächsten Silbe** gehört (Konsonantengruppen, die einen einzigen Laut bezeichnen, werden als ein Konsonant geführt: *ch*, *sch*, *ck*, *th*, *sh*, *rh* - **allerdings**: *pf* und *st* werden getrennt):

> Fens - **t** er

Steht also ein Konsonant zwischen zwei Vokalen, so wird getrennt.

> Pa – ket
>   Vo – gel

Stehen mehrere Konsonanten zusammen, so wird also vor dem letzten getrennt.

> Kell – ner
>   Blind – heit
>   gleich - sam

Also:

> s **i** - ch **e** r - l **i** ch

---

**Weitere Regeln:**

Bei **Vorsilben** wie *be-*, *ge-*, *ver-* kann die nachfolgende Silbe auch mit einem Vokal beginnen:

> **Ver** -antwortung

**Wortzusammensetzungen** werden an den Trennstellen der einzelnen Wörter getrennt:

> Glas-pa-last

Steht **kein Konsonant** zwischen den Vokalen, so wird **zwischen den Vokalen** getrennt (Diphthonge bleiben zusammen).

> Bau – er
>   freu – en

**Fremdwörter** können vor **und** nach dem letzten Konsonanten getrennt werden:

> Sig-nal
>   Si-gnal

Comment: Danke, ab jetzt werde ich also immer noch einmal nachdenken, wenn ich eine Silbe mit einem Vokal anfangen lassen möchte.

Comment: *st* wird aber nur getrennt, wenn man es (hochdeutsch) auch wirklich mit /s/ ausspricht.

Answer (score 4):

Gute Frage!

splattne's Antwort möchte ich hinzufügen, daß "sicherlich" von "sicher" abgeleitet ist. Dieses wiederum wird "si-cher" getrennt.

Es ist verführerisch, "sicherlich" nach dem ch zu trennen, da wir an "mich, dich, sich" denken. Aber das ist ein ganz anderer Wortstamm.

Wenn man ganz genau hinschaut, kann man im Wort "sicher" noch den Lateinischen Wortstamm "secur" `se-cur` erkennen, was letztlich der Ursprung für die Silbentrennung ist.

Comment: Da sich die Trennung im Deutschen nach Sprechsilben richtet, ist die Wortherkunft unerheblich.